# Redux unit tests for actions I got error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to run a unit test for Redux action.test.js with - using jest and react-testing-library.

/src/store/actions/index.js

```
import actionTypes from '../ActionTypes';

export const setLoader = (value, errorMessage = '') => ({
  type: actionTypes.SET_LOADER,
  status: value,
  errorMessage,
});
```

/src/store/ActionsTypes.js

```
const actionTypes = {
  SET_LOADER: 'SET_LOADER'  
};

export default actionTypes;
```

In the test file, Here is part of my test:

```
import * as actions from '../index';

describe('ACTIONS', () => {

    it('should create an actions with correct type', () => {
        expect(actions.setLoader()).toEqual({ type: 'SET_LOADER' });
    })
})
```

I got this error:  expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

```
  ● ACTIONS › should create an actions with correct type

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 0
    + Received  + 2

      Object {
    +   "errorMessage": "",
    +   "status": undefined,
        "type": "SET_LOADER",
      }
```

Any corrections on the code would be extremely helpful Thank you!

> new updates

When I tray to set the `errorMessage`  as I mentioned below:

`expect(actions.setLoader()).toEqual({ type: 'SET_LOADER', errorMessage: 'message'});`

I got a more weird error:

```
    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 2

      Object {
    -   "errorMessage": "message",
    +   "errorMessage": "",
    +   "status": undefined,
        "type": "SET_LOADER",
      }
```

Comment: Well, the setLoader action creator dispatches  an action that contains

```type: actionTypes.SET_LOADER,
  status: value,
  errorMessage,
```

whereas you are checking it against  "type": "SET_LOADER", hence the failing test.

Comment: Yes, I did it. Please check my updates at the main question > new updates

Answer (score 0):

Your `setLoader` action sets the `errorMessage` property to `""` and the `status` property to `undefined`; however, your assertion doesn't account for these properties. You could add these properties to the object being compared in `toEqual`, or you could just verify that the `type` property is `"SET_LOADER"` - it's really up to you.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I thought so too. When I did it. I got a more weird error: 
`expect(actions.setLoader()).toEqual({ type: 'SET_LOADER', errorMessage: 'message'});`
Error:
`Object {
    -   "errorMessage": "message",
    +   "errorMessage": "",
    +   "status": undefined,
        "type": "SET_LOADER",
      }`

Comment: Please check my updates at the main question > new updates

Comment: With your update, you're now expecting the `errorMessage` property to be `"message"`, but it's being set to `""` by your `setLoader` action. And you're still not checking the `status` property.

Comment: No, I can find the `value` of the `status`. 
Any chance to mock up this data with `Jest`?